# Better way to return from recursive function when there are 2^n conditions

Tags: java, recursion, return

Suppose I have `n = 3` `boolean` variables -- `a`, `b` and `c` in `Java`.

These variables can have a total of `8 (2^n = 2^3)` combinations.

These conditions are used to determine the `return` statement in a `recursive` function as follows:

```
static int recursiveFunc(int x){

    boolean a, b, c;

    a = getBoolVal(x);
    b = getBoolVal(x + 1);
    c = getBoolVal(x + 2);

    if(a == true && b == true && c == true)        //7
        return recursiveFunc(x + 1) + recursiveFunc(x + 2) + recursiveFunc(x + 3);

    else if(a == true && b == true && c == false)  //6
        return recursiveFunc(x + 1) + recursiveFunc(x + 2);

    else if(a == true && b == false && c == true)  //5
        return recursiveFunc(x + 1) + recursiveFunc(x + 3);

    else if(a == true && b == false && c == false) //4
        return recursiveFunc(x + 1);

    else if(a == false && b == true && c == true)  //3
        return recursiveFunc(x + 2) + recursiveFunc(x + 3);

    else if(a == false && b == true && c == false) //2
        return recursiveFunc(x + 2);

    else if(a == false && b == false && c == true) //1
        return recursiveFunc(x + 3);

    else                                           //0
        return 0;

}

static boolean getBoolVal(int x){

    if(some condition with respect to x)
        return true;

    else
        return false;

}
```

As you can see, the number of conditions will get pretty lengthy with increasing value of `n`.

However, the return statement can be *generated* easily in `n + 2` steps (instead of `2^n`) as follows:

```
String returnStat = "";

if(a == true)
    returnStat += "recursiveFunc(x + 1) + ";

if(b == true)
    returnStat += "recursiveFunc(x + 2) + ";

if(c == true)
    returnStat += "recursiveFunc(x + 3) + ";

if(returnStat == "")
    returnStat = "0";

else
    returnStat = returnStat.substring(0, returnStat.length() - 3); //removing extra " + "
```

Is there anyway in which I can return `returnStat` as a statement? Perhaps, something like --

```
return stringToCode(returnStat);
```

If not, how to overcome this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

recursiveFunc returns an int, so just add up the ints:

```
int result = 0;

if (a)
    result += recursiveFunc(x + 1);
if (b)
    result += recursiveFunc(x + 2);
if (c)
    result += recursiveFunc(x + 3);

return result;
```

Comment: Pretty sure. Why would it not? Your original example is just adding up the calls to recursiveFunc and returning the sum, this is too, just less directly (but much more cleanly).